# Does `find` return directories that are not on the file system?

Tags: filesystems, find, osx

I'm trying to identify where the python site-package matplotlib is installed on my computer. I ran `find ./ -name matplotlib` at the top most directory (called the root, no?) and was returned the following:

```
.//System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib
.//System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib
```

When I list the folders underneath Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

I only see a folder for python 3.5, **contrary** to what `find` returned.

```
Anjalis-MBP:Versions ahanagrawal$ ls -a

.   ..  3.5

Anjalis-MBP:Versions ahanagrawal$
```

Why is this so?

Comment: are those other two automounted, perhaps? If you `cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`, does it work?

Comment: Yes that works. What does it mean for the files to be automounted? I believe that your usage of the word differs from how it is normally used (to describe automatic data transfers, I believe).

Comment: It means that there's a server process that's configured to mount those directories from (likely) another system.

Comment: Whether this happens depends on whether the find implementation is able to trigger an automount action or not.

Comment: <code>./</code> is not the root directory. Remove the initial dot.

Comment: `/Library` and `/System/Library` are distinct directory trees.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You're referencing the command I used, right? It should really be `find . -name matplotlib`, I take? Then what does `./` do? I don't believe it has restricted where we search by specifying another directory.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You're right. I looked in the wrong directory. I don't automounting (which I don't know about nor believe to be a default behavior) is to blame.

Comment: "./" and "." would do the same thing in this case; they both start at the current directory.  You would do "/" for the root (top of the tree).

Comment: I think OSX automatically exposes the content of some archives (bundles? I don't remember the right word) as files. This is a form of automounting. I don't know how it works, hopefully someone who does will answer.

Comment: Have you tried `locate matplot`?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather an OSX specific question instead of a find problem. There exists two "Library" directories by default:

```
/System/Library
```

for all users and a user specific one in your home folder

```
/Users/yourUsername/Library
```

You sound a little unfamiliar with unix path syntax, so I guess you did the following:

```
cd /
find ./ ....
```

You copied the String Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions and in a new shell which opens by default in your home directory

```
/Users/yourUsername
```

you did the following:

```
cd Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

and you actually end up in

```
/Users/yourUsername/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

Guess: you have installed version 2.6 and 2.7 system wide and 3.5 only for your user.